# Module Selection tab is missing in Prestashop 1.7.4

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've just installed two instances of Prestashop on my local server from the same downloaded zip.  However on one install, the module "selection" tab is missing, preventing me from installing modules placed into the module folder.

I've tried clearing the cache folder to no avail.

Would appreciate any insight into the matter.

Kind Regards
Musaffar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug!
Waiting for the team to fix it.

**But here is a work around:**
Access the `installed modules` tab.

[image]

Above in the url, change `manage` with `catalog` as follow:

[image]

And finally, if you want to search a module you are building, or any other module, directly search it using the search bar  (the category menu, can suffer problems, it doesn't show well, you can use the developer inspector, and change the css (set the z-index to a big number, something like 5000)), so it can be shown if you want! but it's faster to directly search for what you want.

[image]

And here you can see your module, you are building. If that's what you're searching, you can install it too.